# How to compare two cell elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell

I am using two cells for storing the targeted and the expected value of a neural network process in matlab. I have used two 1*1 cell array for storing the values respectively. And here is my code.

```
cinfo=cell(1,2)
cinfo(1,1)=iter(1,10)%value is retrieved from a dataset iter
cinfo(1,2)=iter(1,11)
amp1=cinfo(1,1);
amp2=cinfo(1,2);
if amp1 == amp2
       message=sprintf('NOT DETECTED BY THE  DISEASE');
       uiwait(msgbox(message));
```

But when i run the above code, the get the following error :

```
??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
Error in ==> comparison at line 38
if amp1 == amp2
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I would suggest exploring [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and figuring it out from there.

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks. And ya i have seen cellfun. But can cellfun be used for comparing two numbers. ?

Comment: You have cell array of numbers there and answer to your question is - Yes.

Comment: Ya. It worked using cellfun()!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you indexed things. A 1x1 cell array does not make a lot of sense, instead get the actual element in the single cell, by indexing with curly brackets:

```
amp1=cinfo{1,1}; # get the actual element from the cell array, and not just a
amp2=cinfo{1,2}; # 1x1 cell array by indexing with {}
if (amp1 == amp2)
  ## etc...
```

However, note that if `amp1` and `amp2` are not scalars the above will act weird. Instead, do

```
if (all (amp1 == amp2))
  ## etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html). That will work even if the cell's contents have *different sizes*.

Example:

```
cinfo=cell(1,2);
cinfo(1,1) = {1:10}; %// store vector of 10 numbers in cell 1
cinfo(1,2) = {1:20}; %// store vector of 20 numbers in cell 2
amp1 = cinfo(1,1); %// single cell containing a length-10 numeric vector
amp2 = cinfo(1,2); %// single cell containing a length-20 numeric vector
if isequal(amp1,amp2)
    %// ...
```

In this example, which parallels your code, `amp1` and `amp2` are cell arrays consisting of a single cell which contains a numeric vector. Another possibility is to directly store each cell's *contents* into `amp1`, `amp2`, and then compare them:

```
amp1 = cinfo{1,1}; %// length-10 numeric vector
amp2 = cinfo{1,2}; %// length-20 numeric vector
if isequal(amp1,amp2)
    %// ...
```

Note that even in this case, the comparisons `amp1==amp1` or `all(amp1==amp2)` would give an error, because the vectors have different sizes.